# Multiple entries on PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue in my code when I try to put multiple entries. I tried different solutions, but the problem was not solved. The only problem is to get the value of the field 'valor'

```
<? $produtocotacao = "select * from cadcotacao2 WHERE idcotacao = '$idcotacao' ORDER by id DESC";
$result = mysql_query ($produtocotacao, $marechal) or die(mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $id = $linha["id"];
    $idproduto = $linha["idproduto"];
    $produto = $linha["produto"];
    $user = $linha["user"];

    ?>
    <form id="form6" method="post" action=""><tr>
    <td align="center"><? echo $linha['idproduto']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><? echo $linha['produto']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"> 
    <input name="id6[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $linha['id']; ?>" />
    <input name="idcotacao[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $idcotacao; ?>" />
    <input name="idproduto[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $linha['idproduto']; ?>" />
    <input name="idfornecedor[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo "teste"; ?>" />
    <input name="ip[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $ip; ?>" />
    <input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor" placeholder="Ex: 110,50" class="m-wrap span6" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <?
    if(isset($_POST['done2'])){

        $cotacao = array();

        $cotacao[] = array('id' => $linha['id'], 'idcotacao' => $idcotacao, 'idproduto' => $idproduto, 'idfornecedor' => "teste", 'ip' => $ip, 'valor' => $_POST['valor']);

        foreach ($cotacao as $rst) {
            $id = $rst['id'];
            $idcotacao = $rst['idcotacao'];
            $idproduto = $rst['idproduto'];
            $idfornecedor = $rst['idfornecedor'];
            $ip = $rst['ip'];
            $valor = $rst['valor'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `cadcotacao4` (`ip`, `idcotacao`, `idproduto`, `idfornecedor`, `valor`) VALUES ('{$ip}', '{$idcotacao}', '{$idproduto}', '{$idfornecedor}', '{$valor}');";

            if(mysql_query($sql)){
                $erro = "Cotação Respondida!";
            }
        }

    }
} ?>
```

The code is recording in mysql these lines below:

```
id  timestamp           ip           idforn idprod  forn    valor
47  2016-08-25 15:47:45 179.209.99.217  2   6745    teste   Array
48  2016-08-25 15:47:45 179.209.99.217  2   1       teste   Array
```

Comment: `$_POST['valor']` is an array, and you're using it in a string context, which causes php to issue a warning and give you the literal word `Array` as the array's "value". Since you haven't mentioned getting/seeing that warning, you're probably running with display_errors/error_reporting DISABLED. That's a bad decision. They should NEVER be off on a devel/debug box.

Comment: Hi Marc B. I'm not seeing this warning. The error_reporting(E_ALL) is enabled. Do you have any solution?

Comment: what about display_errors? if that's off, the errors/warnings are simply logged somewhere. either turn on the display, or religiously check where they do get logged

Comment: Ok, we know that warning exists. I'll check the display_errors, but do you have any solution to the problem above?

Comment: Why is there a select here?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with your question is that your code seems very flawed structurally. Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

It seems you are making the classic PHP novice mistake of not realising that ALL PHP code on a page is executed (on the server) before any dynamic HTML and/or JavaScript etc. is executed on the client end.

So, I would tend to put any server end processing at the start of your script - to remind you that it will get done first - putting POSTed form/results data processing first of all, followed with preparation of data to display on your new page.

Secondly if you are using multiple type inputs(valor[]), it only really make sense if you are repeating the inputs within one form - so why are you redeclaring the form for every row? Only ONE form will be POSTed.

**Either use one form with repeating multiple inputs** (if you want to change multiple rows with one submit) **OR use separate forms (preferably differently named) with simple inputs** (valor)(to display multiple results but only change one at a time) instead of multiples (valor[]).

So, I would rearrange your code something like this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['done2'])){
            $ids=$_POST['id6'];
            $idcotacaos = $_POST['idcotacao'];
            $idprodutos = $_POST['idproduto'];
            $idfornecedors = $_POST['idfornecedor'];
            $ips = $_POST['ip'];
            $valors = $_POST['valor'];
            $i=0;
            foreach($ids as $id)
            {
                $idcotacao = $idcotacaos[$i];
                $idproduto = $idprodutos[$i];
                $idfornecedor = $idfornecedors[$i];
                $ip = $ips[$i];
                $valor = $valors[$i];

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `cadcotacao4` (`ip`, `idcotacao`, `idproduto`, `idfornecedor`, `valor`) VALUES ('{$ip}', '{$idcotacao}', '{$idproduto}', '{$idfornecedor}', '{$valor}');";

                if(mysql_query($sql)){
                    $erro = "Cotação Respondida!";
                }
                $i++;
            }

        }

        $produtocotacao = "select * from cadcotacao2 WHERE idcotacao = '$idcotacao' ORDER by id DESC";
        $result = mysql_query ($produtocotacao, $marechal) or die(mysql_error());
?>
                <form id="form6" method="post" action="">
<?php
        while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
            $id = $linha["id"];
            $idproduto = $linha["idproduto"];
            $produto = $linha["produto"];
            $user = $linha["user"];

?>
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><? echo $linha['idproduto']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $linha['produto']; ?></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"> 
                <input name="id6[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $linha['id']; ?>" />
                <input name="idcotacao[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $idcotacao; ?>" />
                <input name="idproduto[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $linha['idproduto']; ?>" />
                <input name="idfornecedor[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo "teste"; ?>" />
                <input name="ip[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $ip; ?>" />
                <input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor" placeholder="Ex: 110,50" class="m-wrap span6" />
                <input type="submit" name="done2" value="Save Changes">
                </td>
                </tr>

<?php
        } 
?> 
                </form>
```

Bit of a change looping through the ids and getting the elements of each of the other multiple[] POST values within that loop then executing the sql using those elements. Hoping that's the kind of thing you were trying to achieve.

Comment: There are other improvements you could make like making idcotacao a single input outside the loop - similarly idfornecedor. Then you would just pick up the single values from the POST array.